# EE 3.1: Cannot save templates as file

Tags: templates, ee3, template-manager

I get the following errors in EE3.1:

```
mkdir(): Invalid path
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Filesystem/Filesystem.php, line 87
```

and

```
file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Filesystem/Filesystem.php, line 74
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I'm getting the same but also with this error `Warning Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /***/system/ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:112)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary fix with a patch coming: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21507/creating-template-group-results-in-errors-.-3.1